# How to get value form Input as numbers to calculate gcd?

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, mathjs

I use [math.js](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/1.2.0/math.min.js) to calculate gcd for a series of numbers wich are taken from input. Among the tested options I mention:

- parseInt() and parseFloat()
- IaNr=document.getElementById("nrs").value
- math.gcd(nrs.value);
- math.gcd($("#nrs").val())
- IaNr.toString()

but it doesn't work.
what am I missing, because it doesn't calculate the numbers from input. it works when I provide the numbers directly. ex: `math.gcd(4, 8, 25,74)`

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/1.2.0/math.min.js"></script>  

$(function(){

IaNr=$("#nrs").val()

DoGcd=math.gcd(IaNr)

$("#show").html(DoGcd)
})          

<input id="nrs"  value="14,92,34,78">

<div id="show"></div>
```

Comment: Your question is vague - do you try to pass 12,34,45 to parseInt() for example?, because it won't work.

Comment: i want to pass any set of numbers up to 10, taken form input for which to calculate the gcd

Comment: IaNr will be stored as an Array, so you need to somehow flatten it before passing it to gcd.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry do you have any practical implementation example to take a look at?

Comment: No. It depends on how ajax math requires its arguments, which I don't know offhand. You could try IaNr.toString().

Comment: tried toString(), but no success

Comment: have you tried passing $("#nrs").val() straight to gcd?

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = $("#nrs").val();
var array  = arr.split(',');
for(var i=0 ; i< array.length ;i++){
array[i] = parseInt(array[i]);
}

dogcd = math.gcd(array[0],array[1],array[2],array[3]);
$("#show").html(dogcd);
```

Comment: thx this ia a partial solution, because in the final version there won't be a fixed set of numbers. In the Input people will be able to insert from 2 up to 10 numbers for which to calculate the gcd.

Comment: switch array.length : {make cases for 2 to 10}

Answer (score 0):

```
IaNr = $.map($("#nrs").val().split(','),
    function(val, idx) { 
         return parseInt(val, 10);
    })

DoGcd=math.gcd(IaNr);

$("#show").html(DoGcd);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/60js3bw4/)**

Comment: Check my demo which find GCD.

Comment: it calculates something now, but i don't think it's correct

Answer (score 0):

I build on the solution suggested by @praveenraj9:

```
var arr = $("#nrs").val();
var array  = arr.split(',');
for(var i=0 ; i< array.length ;i++){
array[i] = parseInt(array[i]);
}
```

and adapted to suit my needs.

```
 FaL=arr.length;
 if(FaL===2){$("#show").html(math.gcd(ar[0],ar[1]))};
 if(FaL===3){$("#show").html(math.gcd(ar[0],ar[1],ar[2]))}
 etc
```

if anyoane knows a more elegant / shorter solution I welcome it.

thx for your help.